# VBA Scraping with IE11 - HTML Elements not indexing in VBA Local - Call javascript instead?

Tags: json, ajax, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've been scraping away for the last couple months with no issues, but now I have a site I'd like to access that is a bit more complicated than simple HTML. When I inspect elements, I can find the tag, ID, and name of an input box i'd like to fill, but when I run the code, there are no elements within the VBA locals window for my `ie` object.

I believe this is due to AJAX, but i'm too novice with ajax/javascript to really know for sure.

This is a screenshot of the input box i'd like to fill out:
[image]

and this is the code I'm using:

```
Sub Findie()

Dim ie As Object
Dim userName As Variant
Dim passWord As Variant
Dim strHTML As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim itemRng As Range
Dim testObj As Object


Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set itemRng = sht.Range("A2")

userName = "***@***.com"
passWord = "********"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

strHTML = "http://[MYWEBSITE].com"

ie.Navigate strHTML

'wait for browser
While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)


ie.Document.getElementsByName("username")(0).Value = userName
ie.Document.getElementsByName("password")(0).Value = passWord
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("submit")(0).Click

While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)


ie.Navigate "[MYWEBSITE]" 'after logging in, navigating to this page saves time


While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend


ie.Document.getElementsByName("productId")(0).Value = "12345"
```

This is not an issue with the page loading either, it does not work when I step through.

I'm thinking it will be much easier if I can actually run the scripts that are on the server, but I've never done that using VBA. I'm not really sure how. Here is a screenshot of the scripts available on the server. I don't really know where to go from here, or which method is ideal.

[image]

Comment: Should not it be `ie.document.getElementsByName("productId") `? The name of the input is "productId".

Comment: Yes, my apologies. Error when transcribing the code to this post. I had to change a couple propriety details and muffed that up in the process. I have tried it (correctly) using `getElementsByName("productId")`, as well as the corresponding `getElementById`, and `getElementsByTagName`. I'll correct the mistake in the post. Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Setting ProductID's value?

Comment: @RyanWildry, the value can be set and input, but it's not selecting since it's not a traditional input box. There is no "submit" button, and `.Click` does not work. Which brought me to the idea that calling the scripts that exist on the server may be a less brittle approach.

Comment: Where is the HTML for the button you are trying to click? The first, or second screen shot? Did you try firing an onClick event, or submitting the form?

Comment: Well, there is no button. When a user is manually inputting item numbers, they type in the input box, and press enter. I tried firing "onTrigger", but not "onClick" - and I do not know how to submit a form via VBA.